# Creating Macro for Asset Browser Thumbnail Creation - Need Event for selecting the next Object once current selected Object Has Updated

Tags: scripting, asset-browser, image-sequence

[image: Auto Selecting Next Object in the Asset Browser]

I am creating a macro that will update the thumbnail using the plugin thumb mate, it creates a custom thumbnail for each object in the Asset Browser, because there are so many assets to update their thumbnails I am trying to create a macro to do the job.

So I have done the following

1. Been able to hotkey the plugin event `bpy.ops.thumbmate.update_preview()` to update the thumbnail, the hotkey updates, so that works perfectly
2. I have been unable to locate the action of selecting the next object in the asset browser to then be able to update its thumbnail, the only way to do this is manually by selecting the next object with left clicking the mouse.

### MEANING

When I select the first thumbnail in the asset browser (say to top left one) and then use the hotkey the object updates its thumbnail, BUT I am unable to find the internal event to select the very next object in the asset browser to update the thumbnail.

The only way so far I have been able to achieve this if I physically select the next object to the right in the asset browser by selecting it with a left mouse click!!

### QUESTION

Can anyone advise what the event is in the keymaps to select the next object (thumbnail) in the asset browser so I can hotkey that and thus make the macro?

Macro updates the thumbnail, then moves to the next object as selected and then next object updates and so on as an automated action.

Comment: What code do you have as far?

Comment: bpy.ops.thumbmate.update_preview()  - that code is the event and I have hotkeyed this, currently I have to manually select each asset with the left mouse click and then use the hotkey for the event above, trying to automate the auto selection of the next asset once the above action is complete!

Comment: This is a [third party add-on](https://www.braverabbit.com/braverabbit/tools/thumbmate/#1648206238467-c3d41c00-aed5)... "Select one or more objects[...] Render > Render Selected Objects." It should work with multiple assets selected. Does not work for me at all in 4.0.2. This is off-topic - you should contact add-on developer for support.

Comment: Thanks Martynas, yes I already did regarding the first hotkey He said it was unable to get it to select multiple items as the API is very limited for selection of items in the asset browser

Comment: Sound about right. It is limited.